# Tables are getting created in public schema rather than the other newly created schema in PostgreSQL using PgAdmin4

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin-4

I am working on PostgreSQL and I want tables in a different schema, not in public.
I am using PgAdmin4. I created one schema and selected the same schema and open the Query Tool. I ran the following query to create the table:

```
DROP TABLE IF EXISTS ClassToTable;
CREATE TABLE ClassToTable (className varchar(4000), fieldName varchar(4000), tableName varchar(4000) );
```

But the table is getting created in public schema , rather than the schema which i have created and selected while executing the query.

Can you please help me in resolving this issue or any workaround??

Comment: I don't use pgAdmin, but `CREATE TABLE` creates the tables in the first table of your `search_path`. Did you change the `search_path` before running the `create table` statement?

Comment: Well, i am using Pgadmin which is UI based. I don't know about search_path .Can you please give me more information, so that i can try?

Comment: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-schemas.html#DDL-SCHEMAS-PATH

Comment: Thanks for sharing the docs. Issue is resolved now:)